# Error in Build file: android\app\build.gradle line: 57

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm running **flutter build appbundle** command and getting the error you can see on the image. what's wrong in **signingConfigs**.

```
   signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }
```

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Images of errors are not searchable, and they're often unreadable. They're also not available to everyone. Error messages are text, and can be posted and blockquoted for readability.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the below file into an android folder directly.

[image: location]

Inside the `key.properties` write the below code

```
 storePassword="storepassword"
 keyPassword="keypassword"
 keyAlias=upload
 storeFile=/Users/...your..keystore..location/keystore.jks
```

Also, update the `android/app/build.gradle` file

```
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
   keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible that you are missing `keystoreProperties` file. This file is typically not checked in to source control, so if you are collaborating with others, ask your friends or coworkers to send you that file.

Answer (score 0):

@WSBT is correct after that use code below

```
signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Got the Error solved**: Could not get unknown property 'keystoreProperties'

**Replaced this code**:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}
```

**With this code**: in android/app/build.gradle file.

```
   def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
   def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
   if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
       keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
   }
```

**as suggested here**: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#configure-signing-in-gradle